# Eloquent Query On 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'value' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select sum(gross) as value, first_name from
>   `clients` left join `transactions` on `clients`.`id` =
>   `transactions`.`client_id` where `value` > 0 group by `first_name`)

From this function?

```
$data = DB::table('clients')->leftjoin('transactions','clients.id','=','transactions.client_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(gross) as value, first_name'))
        ->where('value','>',0)
        ->groupBy('first_name')
        ->get();

return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

> SQL is evaluated backwards, from right to left. So the where clause is parsed and evaluate prior to the select clause. Because of this the aliasing of sum(gross) to value has not yet occurred.
>
> Aliases can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses.

So instead of using `value` in where please use `sum(gross)` in where like below.

```
$data = DB::table('clients')->leftjoin('transactions','clients.id','=','transactions.client_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(gross) as value, first_name'))
        ->where('sum(gross)','>',0)
        ->groupBy('first_name')
        ->get();

return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I see how that could work by I get the following error:

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 'value' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: select sum(gross) as value, first_name from `clients` left join `transactions` on `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id` group by `first_name` having `value` > 0)

Comment: Please check my updated post. Actually you can use sum(gross) directly in where condition instead of using alias. And sorry for the having idea that was wrong. In having you can put condition on the grouped field only.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me but I used havingRaw instead and that worked.